# Google Chrome Css Issues And WordPress Child Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I've been working on my first WordPress child theme for a couple of days and have it looking just fine in firefox but when I check in chrome there's odd issues and no matter how hard I try and can't seem to  resolve them.

You can check the site out here...

```
http://stevefleming.co.uk
```

And the list of issues I've found are...

```
Front page: Main text to right of lemon is screwed up.
Widgets: All the headings have disappeared
Navigation: Gone!
Blog Title (and the rest): lemon has gone and top margin/padding has changed.
Blog: List of articles is missing thumbnails
```

I'm hoping that somebody more experienced than myself can spot the mistakes easily because I've been going round in circles for hours.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Managed to fix one of  the issues. Now the thumbnails on the blog page work ok in both firefox and chrome. Had to remove the margin and fix the width in .alignright. Seems like a bit of a hack but it works. Woothemes must be broke I guess.

Comment: Found out the problem with another but can't fix it just yet. Chrome is ignoring font-weight:bold for the nav and is, instead, just not showing it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody with similar issues comes along the answer to all my problems was connected with the list of fonts the theme was listing. The first one on the list wasn't on my machine and Firefox correctly traversed the list and picked one but Chrome didn't

Instead of failing gracefully and giving some kind of message bits that relied on those fonts just didn't show.

I'm learning to loathe Chrome more and more each day.

Steve